# Load external underscore template

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js

I'm having trouble loading external underscore template in my backbone application. The inline template (commented out) works just fine, but external doesn't.

```
$.app.ObservationSummaryView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'div',
    className: 'observation_summary_view',
    // template: _.template('ID: <%= id %><p>Comments:<%= comments.length %>'),
    template: _.template($('#tpl_observation_summary').html()),
    initialize: function(){
        _.bindAll(this, 'render', 'on_click');
        this.model.bind('change', this.render);
    },
    render: function(){
        return $(this.el).html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
    },
    on_click: function(e){
        $.app.app.navigate('observation/' + this.model.get('id') + '/', {trigger: true});
    }
});
```

HTML/Template:

```
<script type="text/template" id="tpl_observation_summary">
<%= id %>
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    (function($) {
    $.app.bootstrap();
})(jQuery);
});
</script>
```

Error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'replace' of undefined underscore.js:1131
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'bootstrap'
```

I'm guessing it has something do with my app being inside a function, but I'm not sure how to solve this.

Comment: Is DOM ready at template compilation time? I think it's not considering how you call the main method.

Comment: Added, same result :(.

Comment: I meant the compilation in the ObservationSummaryView : $(...).html() is called too early and may fail

Comment: I'll be damned... thanks. I guess that's what 20 hour coding marathons will yield. Post it as an answer so I can give you credit :=).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment you call `$('#tpl_observation_summary').html()`, the DOM seems to not be ready and you get `null` as the first argument of `_.template`, thus resulting in underscoreJS not being able to work with a string which is not one.

Then the `bootstrap` method cannot be defined and so cannot be called as a function of `$.app`.

Template initialization can be included into the first `initialize` call of your Backbone views.